# Question closed as not constructive or argumentative with an answer

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, not-constructive

If a question has been closed because it is likely to lead to heated or extended discussion, is it right that a single answer presenting the bias of the first person to respond be allowed to remain?

Comment: Yes. Closing a question does not affect the answers it has received to date.

Comment: I was not asking a question. I am aware that the answers are not affected. I was suggesting that they should be.

Comment: I was answering your question: Yes.

Comment: Is that the stated position of StackExchange?

Answer (score 1):

When a question is closed, the answers to it are generally considered separately; they are not automatically closed at all.

Though if the question gets *deleted*, the answers of course are deleted, too. If the question is that bad of a flame generator, that's likely going to happen.

The question might be reopened, as a general rule (not speaking to the specific case, which you have not linked). So generally, if the answer does not offend on its own then yes, it should be allowed to remain unless the question is deleted.

Comment: A question need not be offensive to be biased in favour of an application or solution. Those who support another application or solution are denied an opportunity to present their case by the question being closed. I did not present a specific case because, to me, it is a general point.

Comment: @Remou In the case of any closed question, less-than-ideal content remains on the site until it is either improved or deleted. The notation on the question that it has been closed, and why, is expected to serve as a "Here Be Dragons" warning to any readers, until that eventual fate is determined.

Comment: A person may present a sensible and reasoned argument that would appeal to a thinking reader and still only show one side of the case.

Comment: @Remou I understand; but closing a question is not meant to deal with the answers, directly. What if the question gets reopened because the community deems that it wasn't so argumentative, after all?

Comment: If the questions is re-opened, the answer can be undeleted. I realise that anyone with sufficient reputation can see a deleted answer, but anyone with sufficient reputation is not new to the community and is likely to know that this is a topic for debate.

Comment: But why should the offending user be merely *closed*, while someone simply answering the question gets *deleted*?

Comment: Because it is the lesser evil. Because the question should not have been asked and therefore should not have been answered. In addition,  some groups within the community are much larger than others and have a much better chance of answering and presenting an opinion before the question is closed than a smaller group. This means that single answers to argumentative/not constructive questions are always likely to be by one group. There will be no balance.

Comment: @Remou - If the question is *that* problematic, it is likely to be deleted (possibly by the second group :-).

Comment: I did not say problematic, I said biased. Well reasoned and an apparent solution, but biased, and now the only solution available. A small group will very rarely have the presence to cause anything to be deleted. I have frequently seen incorrect answers voted up and remain voted up. I was just hoping that this could be a case where might was not right.